# next js 13.4 getting error while build command on plesk

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, plesk, next.js13

I have uploaded my todo app to the plesk, first I enabled the nodejs then run npm run build command, but it shows error

```
> nexttest@0.1.0 build
> next build

- info Creating an optimized production build...
- info Linting and checking validity of types...
- info Collecting page data...
- info Generating static pages (0/4)
- info Generating static pages (1/4)
- info Generating static pages (2/4)
- info Generating static pages (3/4)
- info Generating static pages (4/4)
<w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Caching failed for pack: Error: Unable to snapshot resolve dependencies
<w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Caching failed for pack: Error: Unable to snapshot resolve dependencies
- warn Compiled with warnings

./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/css-loader/src/runtime/api.js
There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.
This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.
Use equal casing. Compare these module identifiers:
* C:\Inetpub\vhosts\indiaonlinepay.com\httpdocs\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\css-loader\src\runtime\api.js
```

[image]

I try deleting the node_modules, .next , package.lock.js file from the root and rerun the command but same issue happen, How to I start next js app on plesk server